# About script execution permissions on Linux shell

Tags: linux, permissions

I've just created a script, let's say, "helloworld.sh".
The script doesn't yet have execution permissons: `-rw-rw-r--`
If I try to execute that script with: "./helloword.sh", I'll get an error message, as expected. But, if I try to execute that same script as: `. helloword`, it will execute with no problems.

How? Why does that happen?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because on Linux the "." (dot) alone is a built-in command that execute the script within your current session with your current shell. This is the same as calling the script with **source** command (the BSD default method). It's almost the same than execute with `bash helloworld.sh`.

When you call the script with `./helloworld.sh` or `/root/helloworld.sh` the shell will try to figure out how to execute it, if the file is a binary, it will simply run, if it is a script, the shell will read the first line looking for the interpreter. To do this, you'll need execution permission.

To simplify:

- One is a command;
- The other one is a path.

You can even run:

```
. --help
```

---

About `.` against `bash`:

This is why we use **.** or **source** to load variables from a file in our session, for example, when we change **~/.bashrc** and reload it without login again.

You can see this happens when you execute:

```
. /etc/os-release
```

All variables defined inside this file will be loaded and available in your current shell session.

The same will not happen if you execute:

```
bash /etc/os-release
```

Because you opened a "new session" inside that **bash** that you called, the new bash executes and close, cleaning the session.

The same process happen if you give execute permission `+x` to the script, because when you call the script with `./` or something like that, a new session will be created too.